# Test iOS app with device of iOS 5.0.1 beta version

Tags: ios, xcode

Now, I use Xcode 4.2 supporting iOS 5.0. Apple has just released iOS 5.0.1 beta 2. I can install it on my iPhone.

I want to test with this beta version, i.e build code from Xcode.

How do I  build code from Xcode 4.2 for device of iOS 5.0.1 beta?

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In exactly the same way that you would do so for iOS 5.0. We can't talk about beta versions of the software, but we can talk about what happens when newer versions of iOS are released. When you connect a device with a newer version of iOS installed, the Xcode Organizer will give you a message like:

> Xcode does not have debugging information for the version of iOS on the device named “Dev iPhone”. Xcode can collect debugging data from the device to enable development with this version of iOS. This process only needs to be done once per iOS version, and will take several minutes.

You simply click OK or similar, and Xcode downloads the necessary debugging data. You can then build to the device from Xcode and use all the debugging tools as usual. This process works for point releases. It is highly unlikely this would work for major updates (e.g. if iOS 6 was released) and it may or may not work for iOS 5.1, depending on the changes included. But when Apple have not released a new version of Xcode to developers, you can be sure it is because one is not required.

It is important to understand the distinction between an updated version of iOS (for the device) and the iOS SDK (for Xcode). A point release of iOS does not necessarily require any change to the iOS SDK, and therefore with Xcode's ability now to download the debugging information on demand ([a feature that has been around for a while](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/11/23/xcode-unknown-ios-detected.html)), you don't necessarily need an updated version of Xcode. Likewise, with Xcode 4.2 you still set the iOS 5.0 as your base SDK even if you are setting an earlier version (e.g. iOS 4.2) as your deployment target. You don't need the iOS SDK v4.2 to target iOS 4.2 for deployment. (Just make sure you add back "armv6" to targeted architectures in your build settings, if you still want to support the iPhone 3G and equivalent iPods, as in Xcode 4.2 this is not included by default.)

Comment: Is it that unclear? Xcode releases are not upwardly-compatible with iOS releases. OP is asking how to use Xcode 4.2 (which doesn't have iOS 5.0.1 support) with iOS 5.0.1, given that 4.2 is the latest Xcode.

Comment: I've expanded my answer to fully explain how the automatic download process for debugging information works.

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't aware you could simply download the debugging data.

Comment: How long did it take you to download the debugging info? In the past I remember it being a quick process but this time with 5.0.1 I've been waiting for upwards of 30 minutes while mtmd and DTDKSymbolHelper grind away but it's still saying "Copying file (1 of 7)".

Comment: Seconds to maybe a minute. Perhaps servers under heavy pressure with public iOS release however.